# Is it a GOOD practice to store Arrays or Objects in a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have noticed not so long ago that I am able to do this in Javascript. I can create a button div and attach an array, object or value to it like so.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = dName
newDiv.value = value;
```

Later on, when the div is clicked I am then able to call on this data like so:

```
function clickFunction(e){
    console.log(e.path[0].value, "clicked");
    var itemArray = e.path[0].value;
    console.log(itemArray.inputRequest.length, "dataReqs needed");
}
```

I was wondering whether or not this is okay. I do not know if the location to this data will always be .path[0]. 
Can anyone confirm whether this is a good practice or not? I am working on a UI that needs lots of automated Divs, so I am trying to keep everything as automated and simple as possible. **No Library answers please.**

Comment: I would strongly advise against doing this. Instead I recommend creating your data structures in  javascript and storing your dom elements in your javascript data structures.

Comment: How complicated are your data structures? If they're simple numbers and / or strings, custom `data-` attributes would do the job.

Comment: You cannot store objects (incl. arrays) in attribute. When you set element' attribute to some value the latter is treated as `string` (ref.: [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-setAttribute), [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082)). So when you pass object, it will be coerced to `string` by calling `toString` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is an opinion, but you will find many 'No's to this answer. Why?

> The basic pattern is MV*. I highly recommend reading this
>   [chapter](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailmvcmvp) of Essential JavaScript Design Patterns.

In the end, it depends of how much data you want to store there. If it's getting to complex, move it to a model or controller. There are options for this purpose ([read here more on HTML data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)).

**If you store more than a simple Number or String, I wouldn't recommend it.**

**Reasons against it:**

- If other people also manipulate your Code, it's easier to follow design patterns so everybody has the same understanding of your code.
- Store your data in a model or inside the controller. Advantages are you don't have to click a button to access them.
- If you store them in a model/controller, you can share the data more easily.
- All of your data will be visible in the DOM. It's just getting really ugly when you look through the rendered HTML and try to find a bug.
- Testing the data is very hard this way.

Comment: Okay I  will go with the keyword or number storing approach in div.data ; and access it from a separate object/array so i dont have to loop to find the right item. Wish i could give you both Answer Credit, thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1):

There are `data-` attributes in the HTML5 specification that were introduced specifically for this purpose.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

So you could rewrite your code to make use of them.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = 'some name';
newDiv.dataset.value = 'some value';


function clickFunction(e){
    console.log(e.target.dataset.value);
}

document.body.appendChild( newDiv );
newDiv.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dvheb0k/

Comment: This works well for `String` types but not objects, unless you want to `JSON.parse/stringify` each time you're changing the value.

Comment: @NoahFreitas of course, but if converting to/from JSON is inconvenient one could also store a key name in a `data` attribute and keep the data in a global object under that key.